# Any applications using map view is crash on just bought MotoE

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, crashes, maps, motorola-moto-e

I've just bought a new Moto E gen2 with Andriod 5.0.2 and every application I start immediately crashes when I try opening any map-related view.

I've updated Google Maps, no effect.

Comment: Probably related to memory issue, but have you tried **uninstalling** and reinstalling Google Maps update? Also, could you expand more on "any map-related view"? Is it 3rd-party maps app? Or Google Maps on Browser?

Comment: Have you looked at logcat to see where the crash is occurring?  The stack trace would be helpful.